# Outlook Shared Tasks - I need to have a Template (up to 10 tasks) that i can copy and save as a new task - ie class names

Tags: microsoft-outlook, scheduled-tasks, templates, tasks

Subject Due Date
Medical Term M/W 8:30-920 - Syllabus  8/29/2020
Medical Term M/W 8:30-920 - Chap 1-4 / Notes  9/2/2020
Medical Term M/W 8:30-920 - Chap 1-4 / Test   9/9/2020
Medical Term M/W 8:30-920 - Chap 5-8 / Notes  9/16/20
Medical Term M/W 8:30-920 - Chap 5-8 / Test   9/23/20

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of Outlook client, as I know, we could only create one task at a time.

I also did some search about such Tasks Template but have not found any useful information so far. If you still would like this feature, you could try to [vote for this feature](https://todosupport.helpshift.com/a/microsoft-to-do/?p=all&s=tips-tricks&f=duplicating-lists-on-windows-and-web) just like what I have already did. Hope this could be achieved soon.